# Unable to update pixels from 1D coordinates in Processing

Tags: loops, file-io, processing, pixel

I wrote a program in Processing which writes the 1D coordinates of black pixels in an image to a text file.

I wrote a second program which should read the text file and recreate the black pixels on a white image to verify the functionality of script #1

The problem is that the second program which should recreate the black pixels on a white image is not doing so.

For the first script, The user opens the gui, hits 2 to open the file browser, then loads a file. The code resizes the file and changes it to black and white. The code then scans for black pixels and writes the black pixel coordinates to a text file with one coordinate per line.

The second script should simply recreate the original image by adding black pixels in those coordinates to a white image. This is to verify the functionality of script #1.

Here's the code for script #1:

```
boolean stopt = false;
boolean writin = false;
PrintWriter output;
PImage input;
int limiter = 0;
void setup() {
  size(350, 500);
// Create a new file in the sketch directory
 output = createWriter("DIRECTIONS.TXT");
}
void draw(){
  background(0, 25, 51);
  //show processed image here.
  text("Click and type '1' to stop", 10, 440);
   text("Click and type '2' to convert image to command file", 10, 460);
    text("Copy DIRECTIONS.TXT to the printer's memory card after", 10, 480);
    if (stopt) {
      writin = false;
       text("finished or stopped.", 10, 420);
    }
    if (!stopt) {
      text("                          ", 10, 420);
    }
    if (writin) {
      stopt = false;
      text("translating image to printer commands", 10, 420);
    }
    if (!writin) {
      text("                          ", 10, 420);
    }
  if(input!= null){
    input.resize(300, 300);
    input.filter(THRESHOLD, 0.5);
    image(input, 10, 10, 330, 330);

     input.loadPixels();
  //Loop through each pixel (use image size instead of pixels.length!)
  if (limiter <= 90000) {
for (int x = 0; x < width; x++ ) {
  for (int y = 0; y < height; y++ ) { 
    color black = color(0, 0, 0);
    color c = get(x, y);
    if (c == black) {
    int loc = x + y * width;
     output.println(loc);
     writin = true;
  }
}
limiter = limiter + 1;
}

  }
  else if (limiter > 90000) {
    stopt = true;
  }
}
}

void imageSelected(File selection) {
  if (selection == null) {
    println("Window was closed or the user hit cancel.");
  } else {
    input = loadImage (selection.getAbsolutePath());
  }
}
void keyPressed() {
  if (key == '1') {
  output.flush(); // Writes the remaining data to the file
  output.close(); // Finishes the file
  stopt = true;
  //exit(); // Stops the program
}
if (key == '2') {
  selectInput("Select an image to process", "imageSelected");
  }
}
```

Here's the code for script #2 (should recreate image loaded into script #1 from text file generated by script #1 but isn't)

```
PImage input;
int tex = 0;
void setup() {
  input = loadImage("white.png"); //mostly blank image in sketch folder 300 x 300 px.
  size (300, 300);
}
void draw() {
  loadPixels();
  input.loadPixels();
  String[] lines = loadStrings("direct.TXT"); //text file with each line being a 1D pixel coordinate in linear order.
  for (int i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
    tex = Integer.parseInt(lines[i]);
    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++ ) {
      for (int y = 0; y < height; y++ ) { 
        color black = color(0, 0, 0);
        //color c = get(x, y);
        int loc = x + y * width; 
        if (loc == tex) {
          pixels[loc] = black;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  updatePixels();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is fixed. Here's the solution:

Script to convert coordinates in text file back to image to verify original converter:

```
String[] input;// input file

void setup(){
  size(300, 300);
  input = loadStrings("DIRECTIONS.TXT");// load DIRECTIONS.TXT

  background(255);// clear image

  loadPixels();
  for(int i = 0; i < input.length; i ++){
    pixels[int(input[i])] = color(0);// for each line in the input file, set that pixel to black
  }
  updatePixels();
  println("done");
}
```

Script to process and image into black pixel coordinates text file:

```
PImage input;// The selected image
String[] output;// The output file

void setup(){
  size(300, 300);
  output = new String[1];
  output[0] = "";// Avoid "null" at beginning
  selectInput("Select an image to process", "select");
}

void select(File selection){
  if(selection == null){
    exit();// exit if the input is null
  }else{
    input = loadImage(selection.getAbsolutePath());// load selected image
    input.resize(width, height);// reszie
    input.filter(THRESHOLD, 0.5);// make everything black and white

    input.loadPixels();
    for(int i = 0; i < input.pixels.length; i ++){// loop through all pixels
      if(input.pixels[i] == color(0)){
        output[0] += i + "\n";// if the pixel is black, write the position to the file
      }
    }
    saveStrings("DIRECTIONS.TXT", output);// save everything
    println("done");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that the `draw()` function is called 60 times per second.

Then in your `draw()` function, you have this nested `for` loop:

```
for (int x = 0; x < width; x++ ) {
  for (int y = 0; y < height; y++ ) {
```

This means that 60 times per second, you're looping over all of the pixels and outputting stuff to a file.

So to fix your problem, you need to change your code so you don't do this anymore.

Taking a step back, you should get into the habit of [debugging your code](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/debugging) to understand exactly what it's doing. This will help you with cases like this, and it will help you understand how your code should function instead. Good luck!

Comment: I modified the code per your thoughts to only loop 90,000 times (the maximum number of pixels in the image)  but the file output is still huge (195,032 KB). Is there any way to reduce this?

Comment: Are you looping 90,000 times every frame? Or total? What are you outputting? How large do you expect the file to be? Can you try with a simpler image with a known output? Like I mentioned, the key to solving problems like this is debugging. Good luck!

Comment: Hi Kevin, I updated the premise based on new updates.